# How to set radio button value using Reactive form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Here is my component class where I try to set a form radio button value to 1:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class myComponent implements OnInit{
    pageForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pageForm = new FormGroup({
            'gndr': new FormControl(1)
        });
    }
}
```

but when the page loaded the Radio button is not set to Male and both options are blank:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gndr" formControlName="gndr" value=1>Male
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gndr" formControlName="gndr" value=0>Female
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

so how can I load radio button value from my component class?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want either one of them to be checked by default manually, you can add the "checked" tag e.g.

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gndr" formControlName="gndr" value=1 checked>Male
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gndr" formControlName="gndr" value=0>Female
    </label>
</div>
```

**Edit**

If you want to use the default value as of **type string**, set in the FormControl:

`component.ts`

```
this.pageForm = new FormGroup({
      'gndr': new FormControl('1')
    });
```

`component.html`

```
...
<input type="radio" formControlName="gndr" value=1>
...
```

If you want to use the default value as of **type number**, set in the FormControl:

`component.ts`

```
this.pageForm = new FormGroup({
      'gndr': new FormControl(1)
    });
```

`component.html`

```
...
<input type="radio" formControlName="gndr" [value]=1>
...
```

Comment: yes but how do I set it from component class based on FormControl: 
'gndr': new FormControl(1)... I thought it should set the checked param. There is no sence to use FormControl and hardcode it in HTML

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood, this should work `'gndr': new FormControl('1')`

Comment: Not sure if you want the value to be of type string, like you suggest in your html view.. but that does not really make any sense to have the string type of 1 and 0.  So if you like you can change the template syntax from  `value=1`  and `value=0` in your inputs to `[value]=1` and `[value]=0`. To make sure that the values are of type number. Then it   should work with your original ` 'gndr': new FormControl(1)`